# Рало и орало

Tags: лексика

Мне попадалось название старинного пахотного орудия и "рало", и "орало". Это разные вещи или разные названия одного и того же предмета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Это одно и тоже](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE)
Корень очень древний, праиндоевропейский, отсюда возможные различия в фонетике.
Хотя довольно странно, "орать" - пахать, а вот "рать" - нечто совсем другое.

Кроме того, рало - форма натуральго налога (оборка) в Древней Руси.